# How to enable autofill acc/password on Safari without verify TouchId, macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, safari

as title
I want the Safari on MacOS autofill account/password without verify TouchId or password same with Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System Preferences > Touch ID > Uncheck Password Autofill**

Works for me on macOS Big Sur beta. Should work for any version.